# The spectral norm of the difference of two rank-$1$ matrices is equal to the sine of their angle

Tags: matrices, spectral-norm, geometric-interpretation

Can someone help me understand either geometric intuition or mathematical proof that how for two unit vectors $a$ and $b$, the following holds:

$$\left\lVert aa^T - bb^T \right\rVert_2 = \sin \theta$$

where $\theta$ is the angle between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $\sin \theta$ should be $|\sin \theta|$.

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce to the case $a=(1,0, \ldots)$, and $b = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0, \ldots)$ ( by applying an isometry to the pair $a$, $b$). Then you can reduce to the case $\dim V = 2$. Now you operate with concrete $2\times 2$ matrices. We have

$$a a^t = \left(\begin{matrix} 1&0\\0&0\end{matrix}\right) $$
and
$$b b^t = \left(\begin{matrix} \cos^2 \theta &\cos \theta \sin \theta \\\cos \theta \sin \theta& \sin^2 \theta \end{matrix}\right) $$

and therefore

$$a a^t - b b^t =\sin \theta \cdot \left(\begin{matrix} \sin \theta &-\cos \theta \\-\cos \theta &- \sin \theta \end{matrix}\right) $$

From the above we can conclude that $a a^t - b b^t = \sin \theta\, \times$ a reflection.

Now it's interesting to figure out what the reflection actually is.

$\bf{Added:}$

Consider the isosceles triangle $CAO$, with heights $OB$ and $CD$.  The projection  of the vector $\overrightarrow{OC}$ on the rays $OA$ and $OB$ are the vectors $\overrightarrow{OD}$ and $\overrightarrow{OB}$, with difference $\overrightarrow{DB}= \sin \theta \cdot \overrightarrow{OC}$.

[image: Projections]

Comment: Your general approach is interesting, but I am sorry : I don't see how the fact that you can factor out $\sin \theta$ of this matrix proves that the spectral norm is $\sin \theta$. Besides, I think it would be better to factorize $-\sin \theta$ instead of $\sin \theta$ in order to get the rotation matrix by $\theta$.

Comment: @Jean Marie: The matrix resembles a rotation, but is in fact a reflection.  When we take a rotation matrix and change the sign of a row ( or column) we get a reflection.  And we can see what the reflection is. The composition of a reflection and a rotation is a reflection.  I do get confused myself, but then, reflection $\det -1$, rotation $\det 1$, like the sign rule.

Comment: This figure helps to understand your point.

Answer (score 2):

$A=aa^T-bb^T$ is a traceless rank-two matrix. It has only two possibly nonzero eigenvalues $\lambda$ and $-\lambda$. Since it is also symmetric, $\lambda$ is real and $\|A\|_2$ is precisely the spectral radius of $A$. Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
\|A\|_2
&=|\lambda|
=\sqrt{\frac{(\lambda)^2+(-\lambda)^2}{2}}
=\sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{tr}(A^2)}{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{tr}(aa^Taa^T-aa^Tbb^T-bb^Taa^T+bb^Tbb^T)}{2}}\\
&=\sqrt{1-(a^Tb)^2}=|\sin\theta|.\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: The exponential of such a traceless matrix, being an element of $SL(2,R)$, has maybe "something to say"...

Answer (score 1):

The spectral norm of a $n \times n$ matrix is defined by

$$||A||^2=\max \text{eigenvalue of} \ A^TA$$

If we take $A:=aa^T-bb^T$, we must look for eigenvectors and eigenvalues of

$$B:=A^TA=(aa^T-bb^T)^T(aa^T-bb^T)=(aa^T-bb^T)(aa^T-bb^T)\tag{1}$$

Let us take the following notations:

$c:=\cos \alpha$ and $s:=\sin \alpha$.

Expanding (1):

$$B:=aa^T+bb^T-c(ab^T+ba^T)$$

- $B$ has $n-2$ eigenvectors associated with eigenvalue $0$: indeed 2 dimensional space generated by vectors $\{a,b\}$ has a $(n-2)$ dimensional orthogonal space. Taking any vector $v$ belonging to this orthogonal space, one has indeed :

$$Bv=a(a^Tv)+b(b^Tv)+... = 0$$

- The two other eigenvectors are $a$ and $b$ ; indeed

$$\begin{cases}Ba&=&(aa^T+bb^T-c(ab^T+ba^T))a&=&a+cb-c(ca+b)\\
Bb&=&(aa^T+bb^T-c(ab^T+ba^T))b&=&ca+b-c(a+cb)\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}Ba&=&(1-c^2)a&=&s^2a\\
Bb&=&(1-c^2)b&=&s^2b\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

$a$ and $b$ are eigenvectors associated with eigenvalues $s^2$, giving the final result.

---

If, instead of the spectral norm, we have the Frobenius norm, defined in this way:

$$||A||_F^2=\sum_i\sum_j A_{i,j}^2;$$

the formula is the same but **with a factor $\sqrt{2}$** on the RHS. Said otherwise:

$$\text{If} \ A:=aa^T-bb^T, \  \ ||A||_F^2=2 \sin^2 \theta \tag{3}$$

For example, if $a=\binom{1}{0}$ and $b=\binom{0}{1}$ whose angle is $\theta=\pi/2$.

$$A:=aa^T-bb^T=\binom{1 \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 0}{0 \ \ -1}$$

has squared Frobenius norm $2$ which, indeed, is equal to $2 \sin^2 \pi/2.$

Proof of the general case:

The entries of $A:=aa^T-bb^T$ are:

$$A_{i,j}=a_ia_j-b_ib_j.$$

Therefore:

$$||A||_F^2=\sum_i\sum_j (a_ia_j-b_ib_j)^2$$

$$||A||_F^2=\sum_i\sum_j (a_i^2a_j^2+b_i^2b_j^2-2a_ib_ia_jb_j)$$

$$||A||_F^2=\sum_i a_i^2 \sum_ja_j^2+\sum_i b_i^2 \sum_j b_j^2-2\sum_i a_ib_i\sum_j a_jb_j$$

$$||A||_F^2=1+1-2\cos \theta \cos \theta$$

giving finally (3).

Comment: I am still looking for a certain intuitive approach. I wouldn't be astonished that using Clifford algebras (aka Geometric Algebra) could provide such an intuition.

Comment: Any comment ?...

Comment: I drew a picture ( on paper) like this: $a=(1,0)$, $b= (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$. Now, if we take the vector $a^{\perp} + b$ and apply the transformation to it ( difference of projections on $a$ and $b$) we get a vector proportional, and the constant is $\sin \theta$.

Comment: @orangekid It is true that you bring an intuitive reason about "what $\sin \theta$ is doing there ?". But, I still don't make the connection with the spectral norm.

Comment: The transformation $a a^t - b b^t$ is $\sin \theta$ multiplied by an orthogonal transform with eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ ( i.e. a reflection) .  There is an intuitive reason, will get a picture

Comment: I got a picture in my answer, it reduces to a problem in plane geometry, not difficult.