# Bound the difference of two outer products $\| u u^T - v v^T \|_F$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, outer-product

Given two row-vectors $u,v\in[-1,1]^n$, I would like to upper bound the Frobenius norm of the difference of their outer products. Formally, I would like an upper bound on $ \| uu^T - vv^T \|_F$. The upper bound should be a function of $\|u - v\|_2$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the Euclidean norm. Do we know such a bound?

Since the entries of $u$ and $v$ are bounded, it is my hunch that an inequality of the form $ \| uu^T - vv^T \|_F \leq O(\sqrt{n}) \cdot \| u-v\|_2$ or $ \| uu^T - vv^T \|_F \leq O(1) \| u-v\|_2^2$ should hold.

*What I tried so far:*

I have tried using the definition of the Frobenius norm which gives that $ \| uu^T - vv^T \|_F^2 = \sum_{ij} (u_i u_j - v_i v_j)^2 = \sum_{ij} (u_i u_j)^2 - 2 u_i u_j v_i v_j + (v_i v_j)^2$. This is not very dissimilar from $\|u-v\|_2^4$ (after expanding) and I tried to make a few case distinctions based on the signs of $u_i u_j v_i v_j$ but this led nowhere (I spare you the details).

I also tried the brute-force upper bound $\sum_{ij}(u_i u_j - v_i v_j)^2 \leq n^2 \max_{ij}\{ (u_i u_j - v_i v_j)^2 \}$ and trying to relate this to $(u_i - v_i)^2$. However, this is tricky because $(u_i u_j - v_i v_j)^2 = (u_i u_j)^2 - 2 u_i u_j v_i v_j + (v_i v_j)^2$ but $(u_i - v_i)^2 = u_i^2 - 2 u_i v_j + v_i^2$; thus, even though I know that $(u_i u_j)^2 \leq u_i^2$ and $(v_i v_j)^2 \leq v_i^2$, I get problems with the term in the middle since if $u_i u_j v_i v_j$ is positive then we may be subtracting less than $u_i v_i$.

Comment: what happens for $n=2?$

Comment: I would call them symmetric PSD rank-1 matrices.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4540917/339790)

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/33289/339790)

Comment: Use $\|A\|_{F}^2 = Tr(A^TA)$ to obtain $$\|aa^T - bb^T\|_{F}^2 = |a|^4 + |b|^4 - 2\langle a, b \rangle^2.$$

Comment: @Mason Thanks for the hint! Indeed, at one point I realized this equality but then I did not know how to continue from there.

Comment: @tranisstor Well, if you want a bound, let $B(x, y) = xy^T$. Since $B$ is bilinear, $$B(x + h, x + h) - B(x, x) = B(x, h) + B(h, x) + B(h, h).$$ You can compute $\|B(x, y)\|_{F} = |x||y|$. Hence $$|B(x + h, x + h) - B(x, x)| \leq 2|x||h| + |h|^2.$$